# How to parse a api for swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Have been researching on the parsing for quite a bit. With plethora of information avilable for JSON nothing seems to explain how to do in a sensible way to extract information with swift 3.

This is what got so far

```
func getBookDetails() {


    let scriptUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781451648546" .

    let myurl = URL(string:scriptUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myurl!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myurl! ) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
        print("THIS ERROR",error!)
            return
        } else{
            if let mydata = data{
        do{
            let myJson = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as AnyObject

           //   print("this is the MY  JSON",myJson) ---> prints out the json 


            if let dictonary = myJson["items"] as AnyObject? {
            print("the DICTONARY",dictonary) // ----> OUTPUT
                if let dictonaryAA = dictonary["accessInfo"] as AnyObject? {
                    print("the accessInfo",dictonaryAA)
                }

            }


        } catch{
            print("this is the in CATCH")
                }
            }      //data
        }
    }
    task.resume()
 }
 }



  OUTPUT :


      the DICTONARY (
    {
    accessInfo =         {
        accessViewStatus = SAMPLE;
        country = US;
      =============
   RELEVANT DATA as in https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?
  q=isbn:9781451648546" 
   ==========================
        title = "Steve Jobs";
    };
}
)
```

Just need to parse through the json data to get the name, author and title of the book with reference to isbn.
Know there should be a better way to do things that is easily understandable to someone new into the language

Comment: Hey will you check this link https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111

Comment: @Dev_Tandel, it wasn't exactly the answer but that link provided some notes that cleared some query regarding the JSON, Thanks

Comment: i know it is not the answer so wrote in commented. i thought it may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, all JSON types are value types in Swift 3 so the most unspecified type is `Any`, not `AnyObject`.

Second of all, there are only two collection types in the JSON type set, dictionary (`[String:Any]`) and array (`[Any]`, but in most cases `[[String:Any]]`). **It's never just `Any` nor `AnyObject`**.

Third of all, the given JSON does not contain a key `name`.

---

For convenience let's use a type alias for a JSON dictionary:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

The root object is a dictionary, in the dictionary there is an array of dictionaries for key `items`. And pass *no options*, **`.mutableContainers` is nonsense in Swift**.

```
guard let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata) as? JSONDictionary, 
      let items = myJson["items"] as? [JSONDictionary] else { return }
```

Iterate through the array and extract the values for `title` and `authors` which is an array by the way. Both values are in another dictionary for key `volumeInfo`.

```
for item in items {
     if let volumeInfo = item["volumeInfo"] as? JSONDictionary {
         let title = volumeInfo["title"] as? String
         let authors = volumeInfo["authors"] as? [String]
         print(title ?? "no title", authors ?? "no authors")
```

The ISBN information is in an array for key `industryIdentifiers`

```
         if let industryIdentifiers = volumeInfo["industryIdentifiers"]  as? [JSONDictionary] {
             for identifier in industryIdentifiers {
                let type = identifier["type"] as! String
                let isbn = identifier["identifier"] as! String
                print(type, isbn)
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the api in two ways

Using URLSession:

```
    let rawDataStr: NSString = "data={\"mobile\":\"9420....6\",\"password\":\"56147180..1\",\"page_no\":\"1\"}"
        self.parsePostAPIWithParam(apiName: "get_posts", paramStr: rawDataStr){  ResDictionary in
//            let statusVal = ResDictionary["status"] as? String
            self.postsDict = (ResDictionary["posts"] as! NSArray!) as! [Any]
            print("\n posts count:",self.postsDict.count)
        }


    func parsePostAPIWithParam(apiName:NSString, paramStr:NSString,callback: @escaping ((NSDictionary) -> ())) {
        var convertedJsonDictResponse:NSDictionary!
        let dataStr: NSString = paramStr
        let postData = NSMutableData(data: dataStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://13.12..205.248/get_posts/")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = nil
        request.httpBody = postData as Data
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error as Any)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse as Any)
                do{
                    if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        convertedJsonDictResponse = convertedJsonIntoDict.object(forKey: apiName) as? NSDictionary
                        // callback  for response
                        callback(convertedJsonDictResponse)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

Using Alamofire

```
                func AlamofirePOSTRequest()  {
        let urlString = "http://13.12..205.../get_posts/"
        let para = ["data": "{\"mobile\":\"9420....6\",\"password\":\"56147180..1\",\"page_no\":\"1\"}"]

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: para , headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("response: ",response)
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["posts"].arrayObject {
                    self.postsDict = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
                print("\n \n alomafire swiftyJsonVar: ",swiftyJsonVar)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
        })
        dataTask.resume()        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in this line

```
if let dictonaryAA = dictonary["accessInfo"] as AnyObject?
```

because `dictonary` here is an array not dictionary. It is array of dictionaries. So as to get first object from that array first use `dictonary[0]`, then use `accessInfo key` from this.

I am attaching the code for your `do` block

```
    do{
      let myJson = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as AnyObject

        //   print("this is the MY  JSON",myJson) ---> prints out the json


            if let array = myJson["items"] as AnyObject? {
          print("the array",array) // ----> OUTPUT
           let dict = array.object(at: 0) as AnyObject//Master Json
           let accessInf = dict.object(forKey: "accessInfo") //Your access info json
           print("the accessInfo",accessInf)                                                             

     }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `AnyObject` for JSON objects is generally wrong in Swift 3

Comment: @vadian Any documentation or any link ?

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37, and it's logical since all JSON types are value types in Swift 3.